# Error Gradle project sync failed Android recien instalado

Tags: android-studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aparece este error y no puedo crear ni un Hola Mundo, alguien que pueda ayudarme, se los agradezco mucho
Gracias
Tengo un core i 7 con 6gb de ram
No me interesa emular solo poder programar

Comment: podrias mostrar tu gradle ?

Answer (score 0):

Fíjate en el manifest algo  tal vez debe andar mal ahí. En mi Caso tenia esta etiqueta 
  `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" android:targetSdkVersion="15" />` , que era de un ejemplo.
Luego Sincronice de nuevo y se salio el error, y coloca las que corresponda ahora actualizadas   `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" android:targetSdkVersion="27" />`